# Вывести текст с учетом Html разметки в ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Всем добрый день, есть текст набранный и отформатированные в HtmlTextEditor.
Но при его выводе через @Html.DisplayFor все теги отображаются как текст.

Как вывести его с учетом разметки.

Answer (score 2):

Воспользоваться хелпером [@Html.Raw(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896(v=vs.111).aspx)

Comment: это если они и в базу легли как теги, а не как например &lt;

Comment: @Dmitry, ну да, раз texteditor, я об этом не подумал... в этом случае тогда дополнительно пройтись методом [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx).